# Unable to delete file from node in drupal 7 using services

Tags: 7, files, services

I want to delete a file from android app. I am hitting this url (mysite/endpoint/file/fid) with DELETE method and I get following response:
 
1

The response comes with 200-ok  status but file has not been deleted.

Anyone who knows please let me know what is the problem.
Thanks

Comment: Check your server logs for errors - if there's nothing in those, you might need to report this as a bug to the services module

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: If there's no error, and the module isn't doing what it advertises to do, you need to report this as a bug to the issue queue on Drupal.org.